# How firebase cloud messaging initialized in android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After adding [fcm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk) to my project I am wondering: how does it works?
I mean - there is no any firebase integration code in my app. I just have followed setup guide, added dependency and plugin in build.gradle.
How does firebase code get called? Is it use some kind of intent filter?

Comment: After setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging in our Android app, your app is ready to receive cloud messages. The next step is to start sending such messages from either the Firebase console or from your (server-side) code. See the [next steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#next-steps) in the documentation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know that I can send messages from console. Question is - how is it work? I don't add any code in my app.

Comment: The FCM handles registration etc in a service, in much the same way you would have if you did it yourself with GCM, however FCM client lib does automatic retry and other error handling that just makes it much easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique used to initialize the Firebase SDK is explained here:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html

> There is a little trick that the Firebase SDKs for Android use to
>   install a hook early in the process of an application launch cycle. It
>   introduces a ContentProvider to implement both the timing and Context
>   needed to initialize an SDK, but without requiring the app developer
>   to write any code.